# Xamarin Webauthenticator and Php

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, webauthenticator

I have almost 4 days with this. I want to use the WebAuthenticator but just can't. It returns "A task was canceled"

This question is for people familiar with Xamarin and WebAuthenticator

Error I get: A task was canceled

Line that crashes:  r = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);

Stack: At the end of this post

The code I use is this: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/main/Samples/Samples.Android (copy & paste and modify when I see it works)

Also I see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android

I think my problem is because I don't know the correct way to finish in the backend

My flow is this:

1- App connects via webview to backend to retrieve a Facebook url, something like this:

https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?display=popup&response_type=code&client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fid.tinypass.com%2Fid%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fidentity%2Flogin%2Fsocial%2Fcallback&scope=email&state=XXXX

2- App then connects via Webauthenticator to that url (just as the github code does)

3- User interact and logged in

4- Facebook redirects to my provider (tinypass, piano.io)

5- The provider then calls my backend

6- The backend does some curl stuff

7- Backend redirects to the callback

I'm using Php, and the last code in it is this:

header("location: xamarinessentials://");

Also tried:

header("location: xamarinessentials://#callback");

header("location: xamarinessentials://#access_token=XXXX");

header("location: xamarinessentials://", true, 302);

I have tried this flow manually via the browser in desktop, and all works fine. Of course, it fails because there is no xamarinessentials://, just in the app

I know you need to see the code, and as I said, is the same on github. I downloaded to see how it works and then will integrate to my project with the necessary adjustments

Any idea of what's wrong?

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

at Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticator.PlatformAuthenticateAsync
(Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorOptions webAuthenticatorOptions) [0x001e7] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Essentials\WebAuthenticator\WebAuthenticator.android.cs:96

at LoginSocialPiano.MainPage.webView_Navigated (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.WebNavigatedEventArgs e) [0x0014e] in C:\Users\XXXX\LoginSocialPiano\LoginSocialPiano\MainPage.xaml.cs:63

I'm using VS 2022 17.1.4 - Windows 11 - Real Android device with Chrome 95.0.4638.74

The exact call is in here: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Samples/Samples/ViewModel/WebAuthenticatorViewModel.cs#L61

This is the MainActivity.cs file

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;

namespace LoginSocialPiano.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "LoginSocialPiano", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        static App formsApp;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init(this, bundle);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.ActivityStateChanged += Platform_ActivityStateChanged;

            LoadApplication(formsApp ??= new App());
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnResume(this);
        }

        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnNewIntent(intent);
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.ActivityStateChanged -= Platform_ActivityStateChanged;
        }

        void Platform_ActivityStateChanged(object sender, Xamarin.Essentials.ActivityStateChangedEventArgs e) =>
            Toast.MakeText(this, e.State.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    [Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }, DataScheme = "xamarinessentials")]
    public class WebAuthenticationCallbackActivity : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: *"code ... is the same on github"* - Its not obvious from the links exactly *what* code you have that calls WebAuthenticator. Add the code that uses WebAuthenticator to your question.

Comment: Forgot to mention this question is for people familiar with WebAuthenticator. Anyway, the code is in here: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Samples/Samples/ViewModel/WebAuthenticatorViewModel.cs 

r = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);

Comment: StackOverflow is intended to create Q&A's that are useful for years. While external links are useful, please add directly to question the code that is most relevant. This both saves time for people who want to help, and ensures that the Q&A is still useful in the future, even if the link goes dead.

Comment: try placing the [IntentFilter] on the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity instead of mainactivity to see how it works.

Comment: I clean solution, recompile, deleted the app on the device, remove the IntentFilter from the MainActivity, run again, and the same error 

The app shows a "Resumed" toast

Updated the question with the MainActivity.css file

Comment: Have you try the suggetion?

Comment: Yep. I edited the question to include that

Comment: maybe try post your issue here https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues